# Show php data on html page

Tags: php, html, mysql

I would like to ask how could I display data from php class in HTML table I've tried echo theme out with HTML tags but for some reason my code doesn't recognize html tags.

```
 public function getDataUser()
{
    $sql         = "SELECT ID, USERNAME , PASSWORD , EMAIL , PERMISSION_LEVEL FROM USERS";
    $this->_data = $this->_connection->query($sql);
    while ($row = $this->_data->fetch_assoc()) {
       echo $row["ID"] .$row["USERNAME"] . $row["PASSWORD"]. $row["EMAIL"]  . $row["PERMISSION_LEVEL"];
    echo"<br />";
    }
    return $this->_data;
}
```

this br tag doesn't work.

Comment: just use `echo '<br>';`

Comment: Have you tried adding a space between echo and "<br />"?

Comment: also, if you want to use html, you can close php and then reoppen it. `?><br><?php` for example.

Comment: A space makes no difference on an `echo`. but it sure does look better!

Comment: *"this br tag doesn't work."* - So tell us and the question is; do your rows show up if you remove it? I'm thinking "scope" issue either way. Try it without the function.

Comment: @JayBlanchard *Ignored comments, now in progress...* but we do have an answer though! *Will ye lookah dat!* It's magic.

Comment: Yes data shows but in one row

Comment: Ohhhhh.. "one" row. Ok. which one?

Comment: All the data from databes echo out but in one line

Comment: Ah ok. Well add `<br>` between your rows then. I.e. `echo $row["ID"] . "<br>" . $row["USERNAME"] . "<br>" . $row["PASSWORD"]` etc. try that and let me know if it works. If so, I will post it as an answer.

Comment: Tried but doesnt work,Is it problem that I have no <html> </html> tags

Comment: That shouldn't matter. What does the rest of your code look like? People have been posting answers that have been downvoted / deleted because of what you posted. I nearly posted an answer earlier, and glad I didn't. At this point, your question is unclear. Even without html tags, you should still be able to output using `<br>` tags. How are you using this anyway? Nota: I can't keep commenting back and forth like this.

Comment: You are absolutly right . It is really unclear , but I couldn't explain it better. My problem is that I'm trying to output something what I've got from database , but for some uknown reason I cannot format the output. I've tried all the documentation examples

Answer (score 0):

As you return the data, maybe you want only to test the received data:
then you can use print_r (between <pre> tags):

```
public function getDataUser()
{
    $sql         = "SELECT ID, USERNAME , PASSWORD , EMAIL , PERMISSION_LEVEL FROM USERS";
    $this->_data = $this->_connection->query($sql);
    while ($row = $this->_data->fetch_assoc()) {
echo "<pre>";
print_r($row);
echo "</pre>";
    }
    return $this->_data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
public function getDataUser()
{
    $sql = "SELECT ID,USERNAME,PASSWORD,EMAIL,PERMISSION_LEVEL FROM USERS";
    $this->_data = $this->_connection->query($sql);
    while ($row = $this->_data->fetch_assoc()) {
      //do print_r() to check wether data is coming or not
      echo '<pre>';
      print_r($row);
      echo '</pre>';

      //or you can print directly value by $row['ID']." ".$row['USERNAME'] by this way
    }
    return $this->_data;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
echo $row["ID"] .$row["USERNAME"] . $row["PASSWORD"]. $row["EMAIL"]  . row["PERMISSION_LEVEL"]. " <br>";
```